# After edit in templates of MediaWiki, MediaWiki is not refreshing the content of pages

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

if i make changes in the template in mediawiki, the effects are not shown on the page using the template until i edit the page and re-save the page. How to reflect  the changes in all other pages?

Earlier:
[[Trivia::{{{Trivia|}}}]]

Suppose i apply style to an element in template:

[[Trivia::{{{Trivia|}}}]]

Then, the changes not shown in the pages using this template.

Comment: Your [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue) is probably not set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a template transcluded on many pages like this, MediaWiki has to update all the affected pages. However, it doesn't do this by default, as in the default configuration, MediaWiki is only run when someone requests a page. If MediaWiki has to update hundreds (or in Wikipedia's case, millions) of pages when someone requests a page, then that person's request would take a very long time to complete.

Instead, MediaWiki has a concept of "jobs". Jobs can be triggered by various actions. For example, after deleting a page, all links to that page must turn from blue to red; and after changing a category in a template, all pages that transclude that template must switch to using the new category. [By default](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgJobRunRate), MediaWiki runs one of these jobs per page view. This is ok for some sites, but depending on your usage patterns, it might not update all the pages fast enough for you.

To work around this problem, MediaWiki introduced a "[job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue)". By using this job queue, you can run jobs in batch processes in the background, so jobs are completed quickly and requests aren't slowed down by having to process jobs. See the link above for how to set the job queue up.

Comment: Thanks, I will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Other solution would be creating a cron job which would run the `runJobs.php` script from `maintenance` catalogue, let's say, once an hour (or more or less frequently, according to your needs).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.